# Change the Text Field for Required Field in Oracle Forms 6i

Tags: forms, oracle, validation, oracleforms, required

I want to display the required text field in star symbol 
    if user didnt enter any values it should change the Border color to red 
    if user enter values it should Change the Border color to green

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't simply change border color of an item. You can change background nad text color.

You can simulate border color by adding new item which is 2 pixels longer and higher than your item. Place this item under your item and change its background color. It is not as difficult as it looks.

You can change color in WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM on your item using builtin procedure SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY